# Get Day from date string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want build a function (or using a library) that get the day of the week from a date String..

For example, I want transform this date : **1-12-2015** to **"Monday"**

Any help ? 
Thank you

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), use it

Comment: You don't need a library for this, Javascript's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) methods are perfectly fine for this. In particular see [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
var day = days[ (new Date("1-12-2015")).getDay() ];
alert(day);
```

Comment: That was quick, good job!

Comment: @CodeiSir hehe thanks :)

Comment: That's a good answer, thank you